# egl_emulation eglsurfaceattrib not implemented with streaming player

Tags: java, javascript, android

I tied to make a small streaming player from url, but it doesnt work when I run it . I have this error message when I run [this code](http://www.4shared.com/file/3qJYpXOB/Sounds.html):

```
i/o error problem with connection or mem card this 07-31 22:45:01.082: E/Trace(779): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
07-31 22:45:01.753: D/dalvikvm(779): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 71K, 8% free 2498K/2692K, paused 45ms, total 47ms
07-31 22:45:01.763: I/dalvikvm-heap(779): Grow heap (frag case) to 4.019MB for 1536016-byte allocation
07-31 22:45:01.813: D/dalvikvm(779): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 2K, 5% free 3996K/4196K, paused 39ms, total 39ms
07-31 22:45:01.882: D/dalvikvm(779): GC_CONCURRENT freed <1K, 5% free 3996K/4196K, paused 7ms+4ms, total 68ms
07-31 22:45:02.303: D/dalvikvm(779): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1K, 5% free 4292K/4484K, paused 28ms, total 33ms
07-31 22:45:02.392: D/dalvikvm(779): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1K, 4% free 4852K/5036K, paused 13ms+5ms, total 56ms
07-31 22:45:02.392: D/dalvikvm(779): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 27ms
07-31 22:45:02.603: D/dalvikvm(779): GC_CONCURRENT freed 5K, 3% free 5599K/5772K, paused 13ms+15ms, total 78ms
07-31 22:45:02.723: D/libEGL(779): loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_emulation.so
07-31 22:45:02.733: D/(779): HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0x2a149660, tid 779
07-31 22:45:02.753: D/libEGL(779): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_emulation.so
07-31 22:45:02.753: D/libEGL(779): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_emulation.so
07-31 22:45:02.863: W/EGL_emulation(779): eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
07-31 22:45:02.872: D/OpenGLRenderer(779): Enabling debug mode 0
07-31 22:45:26.834: D/dalvikvm(779): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 13K, 3% free 5662K/5796K, paused 37ms, total 42ms
07-31 22:45:26.854: I/dalvikvm-heap(779): Grow heap (frag case) to 7.110MB for 1536016-byte allocation
07-31 22:45:26.983: D/dalvikvm(779): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 2K, 2% free 7160K/7300K, paused 127ms, total 127ms
07-31 22:45:27.104: D/dalvikvm(779): GC_CONCURRENT freed 2K, 2% free 7158K/7300K, paused 5ms+25ms, total 116ms
07-31 22:45:28.113: E/ActivityThread(779): Failed to find provider info for com.google.plus.platform
07-31 22:45:28.225: I/Ads(779): To get test ads on this device, call adRequest.addTestDevice(AdRequest.TEST_EMULATOR);
07-31 22:45:28.694: D/dalvikvm(779): GC_CONCURRENT freed 246K, 5% free 8397K/8764K, paused 7ms+86ms, total 344ms
07-31 22:45:28.764: D/dalvikvm(779): DexOpt: --- BEGIN 'ads-274152189.jar' (bootstrap=0) ---
07-31 22:45:29.504: D/dalvikvm(779): DexOpt: --- END 'ads-274152189.jar' (success) ---
07-31 22:45:29.504: D/dalvikvm(779): DEX prep '/data/data/com.example.wadi3mrad/cache/ads-274152189.jar': unzip in 1ms, rewrite 732ms
07-31 22:45:29.714: I/dalvikvm(779): Total arena pages for JIT: 11
07-31 22:45:29.714: I/dalvikvm(779): Total arena pages for JIT: 12
07-31 22:45:29.714: I/dalvikvm(779): Total arena pages for JIT: 13
07-31 22:45:29.714: I/dalvikvm(779): Total arena pages for JIT: 14
07-31 22:45:29.714: I/dalvikvm(779): Total arena pages for JIT: 15
07-31 22:45:29.744: I/dalvikvm(779): Total arena pages for JIT: 16
07-31 22:45:29.744: I/dalvikvm(779): Total arena pages for JIT: 17
07-31 22:45:29.964: I/Ads(779): adRequestUrlHtml: <html><head><script src="http://media.admob.com/sdk-core-v40.js"></script><script>AFMA_getSdkConstants();AFMA_buildAdURL({"preqs":0,"session_id":"11746569270251508533","seq_num":"1","slotname":"a1511e375bc5d44","u_w":320,"msid":"com.example.wadi3mrad","cap":"m,a","js":"afma-sdk-a-v6.4.1","bas_off":0,"net":"ed","app_name":"1.android.com.example.wadi3mrad","hl":"en","gnt":3,"carrier":"310260","u_audio":4,"kw":[],"u_sd":1.5,"simulator":1,"ms":"1J0LR_q7rarpfanzlUqRxxSwXQF5TkDYiVp9EsUhg_cbbamTHRqu2G_bRaYJD7hS3eIw91owfAhtYebMtrKmExifoiFWh-oHWG2wDoLVm1NlrPMQiNAFqfVV9uLipR9jbkvU9lHGHBOoNdWX2bE-fmQmB56angkcKOPjBh5pBwMeUkoB-UqashoJidpPEQ-Qrxf7oQJ04Sm7-sypyWKsyJLiegK06lZX87ayKpOkL9rsZBqVZ8lovRgupFT-fQGdolIjfo31dO_cQMxApYODUug9IE12jJ8uMk2l8iFYHwJrCCGD0T-zhgJSqhVbiPpKgY6TJff5dlBTkSyMUc-jXw","isu":"B3EEABB8EE11C2BE770B684D95219ECB","format":"320x50_mb","oar":0,"ad_pos":{"height":0,"visible":0,"y":0,"x":0,"width":0},"u_h":533,"pt":1,"bas_on":0,"ptime":0});</script></head><body></body></html>
07-31 22:45:30.274: W/EGL_emulation(779): eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
07-31 22:45:30.814: W/chromium(779): external/chromium/net/disk_cache/backend_impl.cc:1835: [0731/224530:WARNING:backend_impl.cc(1835)] Destroying invalid entry.
07-31 22:45:33.914: I/Ads(779): Received ad url: <url: "http://googleads.g.doubleclick.net:80/mads/gma?preqs=0&session_id=11746569270251508533&seq_num=1&u_w=320&msid=com.example.wadi3mrad&cap=m%2Ca&js=afma-sdk-a-v6.4.1&bas_off=0&net=ed&app_name=1.android.com.example.wadi3mrad&hl=en&gnt=3&carrier=310260&u_audio=4&kw&u_sd=1.5&ms=1J0LR_q7rarpfanzlUqRxxSwXQF5TkDYiVp9EsUhg_cbbamTHRqu2G_bRaYJD7hS3eIw91owfAhtYebMtrKmExifoiFWh-oHWG2wDoLVm1NlrPMQiNAFqfVV9uLipR9jbkvU9lHGHBOoNdWX2bE-fmQmB56angkcKOPjBh5pBwMeUkoB-UqashoJidpPEQ-Qrxf7oQJ04Sm7-sypyWKsyJLiegK06lZX87ayKpOkL9rsZBqVZ8lovRgupFT-fQGdolIjfo31dO_cQMxApYODUug9IE12jJ8uMk2l8iFYHwJrCCGD0T-zhgJSqhVbiPpKgY6TJff5dlBTkSyMUc-jXw&format=320x50_mb&oar=0&u_h=533&bas_on=0&ptime=0&u_so=p&imbf=%40installed_markets%40&output=html&region=mobile_app&u_tz=0&client_sdk=1&ex=1&slotname=a1511e375bc5d44&kw_type=broad&gsb=3g&caps=inlineVideo_interactiveVideo_mraid1_th_autoplay_mediation_sdkAdmobApiForAds_di&eisu=Tk6HBrFwIQ9knxvuW0ih85luqMNl3BU3Pt13TBg__ERG9QJSQ0X7yP6jBBrROQQ-9cOwBC_hKK2FwuQ0dGiLc5TQfok0Ftjr_o8v9TnXfkltfciz15utRyMY3eUWFa60&et=102&jsv=53" type: "admob" afmaNotifyDt: "null" activationOverlayUrl: "null" useWebViewLoadUrl: "false">
07-31 22:45:34.005: I/Ads(779): Ad url modified to http://googleads.g.doubleclick.net:80/mads/gma?preqs=0&session_id=11746569270251508533&seq_num=1&u_w=320&msid=com.example.wadi3mrad&cap=m%2Ca&js=afma-sdk-a-v6.4.1&bas_off=0&net=ed&app_name=1.android.com.example.wadi3mrad&hl=en&gnt=3&carrier=310260&u_audio=4&kw&u_sd=1.5&ms=1J0LR_q7rarpfanzlUqRxxSwXQF5TkDYiVp9EsUhg_cbbamTHRqu2G_bRaYJD7hS3eIw91owfAhtYebMtrKmExifoiFWh-oHWG2wDoLVm1NlrPMQiNAFqfVV9uLipR9jbkvU9lHGHBOoNdWX2bE-fmQmB56angkcKOPjBh5pBwMeUkoB-UqashoJidpPEQ-Qrxf7oQJ04Sm7-sypyWKsyJLiegK06lZX87ayKpOkL9rsZBqVZ8lovRgupFT-fQGdolIjfo31dO_cQMxApYODUug9IE12jJ8uMk2l8iFYHwJrCCGD0T-zhgJSqhVbiPpKgY6TJff5dlBTkSyMUc-jXw&format=320x50_mb&oar=0&u_h=533&bas_on=0&ptime=0&u_so=p&imbf=8008&output=html&region=mobile_app&u_tz=0&client_sdk=1&ex=1&slotname=a1511e375bc5d44&kw_type=broad&gsb=3g&caps=inlineVideo_interactiveVideo_mraid1_th_autoplay_mediation_sdkAdmobApiForAds_di&eisu=Tk6HBrFwIQ9knxvuW0ih85luqMNl3BU3Pt13TBg__ERG9QJSQ0X7yP6jBBrROQQ-9cOwBC_hKK2FwuQ0dGiLc5TQfok0Ftjr_o8v9TnXfkltfciz15utRyMY3eUWFa60&et=102&jsv=53
07-31 22:45:34.005: I/Ads(779): Request scenario: Online server request.
07-31 22:45:36.933: E/ActivityThread(779): Failed to find provider info for com.google.plus.platform
07-31 22:45:37.024: I/Ads(779): To get test ads on this device, call adRequest.addTestDevice(AdRequest.TEST_EMULATOR);
07-31 22:45:37.174: I/Ads(779): adRequestUrlHtml: <html><head><script src="http://media.admob.com/sdk-core-v40.js"></script><script>AFMA_buildAdURL({"preqs":1,"session_id":"11746569270251508533","seq_num":"2","slotname":"a1511e375bc5d44","u_w":320,"msid":"com.example.wadi3mrad","cap":"m,a","js":"afma-sdk-a-v6.4.1","bas_off":0,"imbf":"8008","net":"ed","app_name":"1.android.com.example.wadi3mrad","hl":"en","gnt":3,"carrier":"310260","u_audio":4,"kw":[],"u_sd":1.5,"simulator":1,"ms":"WPK9F7kBtD5kC6QOejtyR6jplmB8sxoho1qNRXA1gNy-mGhBVtDhNZ4F6JJEjBvlH-Si9Xip0nRDUuIKNw8tVdIdId3fbGT095Jow0rEhtiVq8PpLB8ZlpN4M31W9O_ftn5e8b23KAL2zrKya8R5VykE8rHMtaedd_Sdp-0-LrX5CheTcbM7T74RQVUr_TKRp0VqEzXo6NVAW5yDI8B719ML8VFh3YS_uGHPLBDf0FMEot5v04Tb5mR-rvBBwiYa4wZH6bybzBnTKlRh-dbYJ-8DQbkapa_J2uRLZBcbiP39MeKfEzMgVO2mMZGeyq_esj6bEF-IEH0j9AWVLAUFpQ","isu":"B3EEABB8EE11C2BE770B684D95219ECB","format":"320x50_mb","oar":0,"ad_pos":{"height":0,"visible":0,"y":0,"x":0,"width":0},"u_h":533,"pt":1,"bas_on":0,"ptime":8809});</script></head><body></body></html>
07-31 22:45:38.504: W/EGL_emulation(779): eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
07-31 22:45:38.824: I/Choreographer(779): Skipped 38 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
07-31 22:45:40.144: D/webviewglue(779): nativeDestroy view: 0x2a14dd40
07-31 22:45:40.174: I/Ads(779): onReceiveAd()
07-31 22:45:40.644: I/Ads(779): Received ad url: <url: "http://googleads.g.doubleclick.net:80/mads/gma?preqs=1&session_id=11746569270251508533&seq_num=2&u_w=320&msid=com.example.wadi3mrad&cap=m%2Ca&js=afma-sdk-a-v6.4.1&bas_off=0&imbf=8008&net=ed&app_name=1.android.com.example.wadi3mrad&hl=en&gnt=3&carrier=310260&u_audio=4&kw&u_sd=1.5&ms=WPK9F7kBtD5kC6QOejtyR6jplmB8sxoho1qNRXA1gNy-mGhBVtDhNZ4F6JJEjBvlH-Si9Xip0nRDUuIKNw8tVdIdId3fbGT095Jow0rEhtiVq8PpLB8ZlpN4M31W9O_ftn5e8b23KAL2zrKya8R5VykE8rHMtaedd_Sdp-0-LrX5CheTcbM7T74RQVUr_TKRp0VqEzXo6NVAW5yDI8B719ML8VFh3YS_uGHPLBDf0FMEot5v04Tb5mR-rvBBwiYa4wZH6bybzBnTKlRh-dbYJ-8DQbkapa_J2uRLZBcbiP39MeKfEzMgVO2mMZGeyq_esj6bEF-IEH0j9AWVLAUFpQ&format=320x50_mb&oar=0&u_h=533&bas_on=0&ptime=8809&u_so=p&output=html&region=mobile_app&u_tz=0&client_sdk=1&ex=1&slotname=a1511e375bc5d44&kw_type=broad&askip=1&gsb=3g&caps=inlineVideo_interactiveVideo_mraid1_th_autoplay_mediation_sdkAdmobApiForAds_di&eisu=qWGBvfsnTzlZ71SU3II4K65ddle29nytPaYLgV8betlkgdB6onfDzXszUkO2ywVXPuibieaAfpG05I9gcws5tsAXAOhEhJ_e1CV-f-GfjiRfrLyYQOPO8m8I7G_N9BHQ&et=99&jsv=53" type: "admob" afmaNotifyDt: "null" activationOverlayUrl: "null" useWebViewLoadUrl: "false">
07-31 22:45:40.644: I/Ads(779): Request scenario: Online server request.
07-31 22:45:43.134: D/dalvikvm(779): GC_CONCURRENT freed 673K, 8% free 9684K/10480K, paused 77ms+23ms, total 217ms
07-31 22:45:43.144: D/webviewglue(779): nativeDestroy view: 0x2a27ff88
07-31 22:45:43.454: D/webviewglue(779): nativeDestroy view: 0x2a3be1c0
07-31 22:45:43.463: I/Ads(779): onReceiveAd()
07-31 22:45:44.044: D/TilesManager(779): Starting TG #0, 0x2a40f250
07-31 22:45:44.964: V/Connection:(779): attempt
07-31 22:45:47.354: V/Connection:(779): fail2
07-31 22:45:47.364: W/System.err(779): android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.
07-31 22:45:47.385: W/System.err(779):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.checkThread(ViewRootImpl.java:4746)
07-31 22:45:47.385: W/System.err(779):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.requestLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:823)
07-31 22:45:47.394: W/System.err(779):  at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:15473)
07-31 22:45:47.394: W/System.err(779):  at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:15473)
07-31 22:45:47.394: W/System.err(779):  at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:15473)
07-31 22:45:47.394: W/System.err(779):  at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:15473)
07-31 22:45:47.394: W/System.err(779):  at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:15473)
07-31 22:45:47.414: W/System.err(779):  at android.widget.AbsListView.requestLayout(AbsListView.java:1819)
07-31 22:45:47.414: W/System.err(779):  at android.widget.AdapterView$AdapterDataSetObserver.onChanged(AdapterView.java:813)
07-31 22:45:47.414: W/System.err(779):  at android.widget.AbsListView$AdapterDataSetObserver.onChanged(AbsListView.java:5958)
07-31 22:45:47.424: W/System.err(779):  at android.database.DataSetObservable.notifyChanged(DataSetObservable.java:37)
07-31 22:45:47.424: W/System.err(779):  at android.widget.BaseAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged(BaseAdapter.java:50)
07-31 22:45:47.444: W/System.err(779):  at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged(ArrayAdapter.java:286)
07-31 22:45:47.444: W/System.err(779):  at com.example.wadi3mrad.Sounds$asyncdownload.onCancelled(Sounds.java:689)
07-31 22:45:47.444: W/System.err(779):  at com.example.wadi3mrad.Sounds$asyncdownload.doInBackground(Sounds.java:597)
07-31 22:45:47.455: W/System.err(779):  at com.example.wadi3mrad.Sounds$asyncdownload.doInBackground(Sounds.java:1)
07-31 22:45:47.455: W/System.err(779):  at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
07-31 22:45:47.455: W/System.err(779):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
07-31 22:45:47.455: W/System.err(779):  at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
07-31 22:45:47.455: W/System.err(779):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
07-31 22:45:47.474: W/System.err(779):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
07-31 22:45:47.474: W/System.err(779):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
07-31 22:45:47.484: V/onpostexecute(779): execuuuuuuuuuuuuute
07-31 22:45:47.484: V/onpostexecute in downloading(779): execuuuuuuuuuuuuute in downloading
07-31 22:45:47.484: V/onpostexecute in downloading(779): execuuuuuuuuuuuuute in downloading
07-31 22:45:47.734: W/EGL_emulation(779): eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
```

Comment: This is just overwhelming!

Comment: Please take a look at this page to improve your chances of getting an answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask

Answer (score -1):

Sounds like this is your main problem:

```
error opening trace file: No such file or directory 
(2) 07-31 22:45:01.753: D/dalvikvm(779):
```